# Weird address in my network

Tags: ip, ip-address, lan

I pinged all hosts in my network. Only my PC and my phone are connected to my network. Therefore I received three addresses, not two. This weird one is `192.168.1.1`. It isn't neither my PC nor my phone so anyone knows what it is?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Do you have a router?

Answer (score 2):

That is probably the router (gateway) address. The router is also a host on your LAN.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to help you with such little information. That IP address could be anything. This being a private address on your network and also ending with .1 would indicate that this is your gateway. So it could be your router. One thing you could try to do is use a tool such as NMAP with Zenmap gui (for convenience) and scan the IP address to get more information about the host.

Try going to that IP address as well in your browser and see whether it is running a web service that will be tell you what it is.

Comment: Nice and friendly network scanner on Android is Fing. It Scan IP, edtect vendor by mac, show host roles, scan ports, guess services, allow easy conect to services. I wish to have similar gui for Win and Linux, but Fing for desktop ugly.